# How to create a single sign in system for my 3 applications

Tags: authentication, web

I have a three web application.

Each of these applications has its own specificity and account database.

I'd like to develop a common login page. The account would be common to all applications

For example, `login.fr?redirect=myApp2` is my centralized connection and redirect to my second application

How to do it?

I thought of 2 solutions:

1. Use OAuth2 or OpenID Connect. But I don't think that's what it's for: it's for a centralized connection, internal to our products. Not an identity provider for external applications.
2. Simply: a connection that holds all user information and generate a JWT for applications

Thanks